# Completely self-contained (and as elementary as possible) introduction to Teichmuller Theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, riemann-surfaces, geometric-topology

Can you recommend a completely self-contained and elementary (as much as it can be) introduction to Teichmuller Theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A Primer on Mapping Class Groups](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9495.html) by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit is a good bet.

You can also take a look at the answers to [a similar question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10514/teichmuller-theory-introduction).